# OpsHub 008 error

Tags: opshub

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this.

I am very new to visual studio, tfs, and coding all together. This really isnt my area but I am tasked with migrating our team foundation server to visual studio online. I looked online and have been reading up about this OpsHub application and it sounded amazing! So long story short. I went to install it on my VM that is current running Tfs 2010. Once I run the installer I get a prompt saying 
"OPS-008: OpsHub visual studio online migration utility requires team foundation server 2012 update 1 object model or above".

Now that is pretty straight forward I know, but the application states 2010, 2012, and 2013. Am I missing something here? I thought this was going to take some work out but if I have to upgrade tfs to 2012 thats taking on another project all together.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Hi, The requirement for the OpsHub Migration utility is the Microsoft TFS Object Model 2012 (preferably) (link: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f30e5cc7-036e-449c-a541-d522299445aa). This is available as a stand alone installation and is actually a bunch of assemblies related to TFS API that the OpsHub tool needs for running. On a side note, we would advice  you to NOT run the utility on the TFS server machine and do so on a local VM instead (if possible). tl;dr; Its the Object model version not the TFS version that you need to install/upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I cant wait to give this a try.

Comment: Great thanks for that! Now I have hit another roadblock of course, its probably going to happen with each step I take.